# set data range php

Tags: php

i have a list with some days listed in a table, so , my database result come like this:

```
$day   = $res->fields['DAY'];

$month = $res->fields['MONTH'];

$year  = $res->fields['YEAR'];
```

and i put they all together to form a valid date

```
// put together the date
$date    = $res->fields['DAY']."/".$res->fields['MONTH']."/".$res->fields['YEAR'];     

// get the present day
$today   = date('d/m/Y');  // 28/10/2011
```

and i check:

```
if($date == $today){
   $backGroundTr = "red";
}
```

setting a `<tr>` background red.

the html is something like this:

```
<tr bgcolor="green">
   <td>31/10/2011</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="green">
   <td>30/10/2011</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="green">
   <td>29/10/2011</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="red"> // this reciave the red bgcolor because is today
   <td>28/10/2011</td>
</tr>
```

now, what i'm trying to do is:

how can i set other color to the next 3 days ? as u can see in the example, i put the green color.

dont know if i was clear, any question, please, be my guest

Comment: Many questions arise: how do you get the other dates? Do you generate them inside a loop? Why is 31 the first date and then the next ones are orderes in descendant order?

Comment: yes, my result is inside of a `while()`, the html is a example, 28 is bgcolor red, i need to set the green color to the next 5 days, as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
if($date == date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+1 day')) ||
    $date == date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+2 day')) ||
    $date == date('d/m/Y',strtotime('+3 day'))){
   $backGroundTr = "green";
}
```

or you can do something like that: (i assume you loop through your days) **(this solution will not work as days are printed in the opposite order)**

```
$green=0;
while ( ... ){
  ...
  if($date == $today){
    $backGroundTr = "red";
    $green=3;
  }
  if ($green>0)
  {
    $backGroundTr = "green";
    $green--;
  }
  ...
}
```

or you can do something like that:

```
if(strtotime($date) > strtotime($today) && 
  strtotime($date) <= strtotime('+3 days',$today)
{
  $backGroundTr = "green";
}
```

Comment: your first option work fine, will make some test and return here with the result.

Comment: Basically when we encounter a "red" day we set variable $green to 3. Every time we loop we check if $green is more then 0, and in this case we set background to green and decrease $green by 1. So in this way we will set background to green for the next 3 days after a red one

Comment: oops just noticed that you print out days in opposite order, so second solution will not work

Comment: i'm testing now setting the day from a diferent month to see if works :)